# '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am attempting to gather some information from one of our systems through an API, this script works completely on my local machine but when running the script from the server it is meant to be ran from, I get the error in the title.

Some information about the server/script:

1. Using requests library in python
2. Created the .pem file myself for request verification
3. Requests made from local machine are verified no problem
4. The script is unchanged from one machine to another
5. Local machine is running Windows 10, server is RHEL Centos 8
6. I can make other verified requests to different systems
7. `openssl s_client -connect` shows me the cipher being used, this cipher is listed in my list of ciphers when running `openssl ciphers`

Here is how the request is generated:

```
response = requests.get(team_search, auth=(api_id, api_key), headers=headers, verify=certificate)
```

Contents of the .pem file are formatted correctly:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
**********************************
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
**********************************
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
**********************************
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Here is the full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.veracode.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/authn/v2/teams/?page=0&size=1000 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/WebApps/access-review-test/PAR/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/path/WebApps/access-review-test/PAR/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/path/WebApps/access-review-test/PAR/AccessReview/management/commands/update_veracodeusers.py", line 41, in handle
    response = requests.get(team_search, auth=RequestsAuthPluginVeracodeHMAC(api_id, api_key), headers=headers, verify=certificate)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.veracode.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/authn/v2/teams/?page=0&size=1000 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I just need to resolve this verification of these requests. I know that I could put `verify=False` but that is not best practice and these requests should be verified at all times